# Tailwind css is not working consistently, properly in vs code (it behaves different than tailwind play)

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Hi I am a beginner just trying to learn tailwindcss. IN vscode it looks like it is styling things (like adding the purple color) but it is not styling things, for instance making the font bigger or bolder. It is giving me different result than the tailwind play. I am using live server so it saves every 1second and automatically update things on the browser. I feel frustrated and stuck, and I wonder why tailwindcss classes are not being applied properly.

[tailwindcss play](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oif2j.png)

```
    <div
        class="bg-purple-500 flex justify-between items-center p-5"
      >
        <h1 class="text-4xl font-bold">BarberShop</h1>
      
        <ul class="inline">
          <li class="inline m-4">Home</li>
          <li class="inline m-4">About Us</li>
          <li class="inline m-4">Services</li>
          <li class="inline m-4">Reservation</li>
          <li class="inline m-4">Contacts</li>
        </ul>
   
        </div>
      </div>
```

[desktop with vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PssC1.png)
[codes in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4VA3.png)

I have tried copying and pasting the exact same code in to the tailwind css play and it is showing as I have expected.

Comment: Consider checking the `content` file globs sufficiently cover the file the code is in.

Comment: I figured it out i think,,, it looks like each time you start a visual code, I need to  run this on my terminal 'npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./dist/output.css --watch
'

Comment: otherwise, some tailwindcss 'seem to be working' but it is ultimately broken and it will not reflect correctly on your browser. Man this took me like 2-3 days to figure it out.